# Django broken OneToOneField

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-users

I have an app running and I made a huge mistake, I've deleted a user from the admin site of my Django app before deleting it's UserProfile.

Now, when I try to see the UserProfiles from the admin site, I keep getting an error, for what I've seen it's a `record not found exception`.

I've got this problem because I cannot use any backup as the latest one is half a month old and all my users will get really mad if they loose all data.

So, how can I do it so I can enter in the UserProfile (It would be best if using the admin site) to delete the UserProfile?

Thanks

Comment: You could try go directly to the delete URL : `mysite.com/admin/myapp/userprofile/1/delete/` obviously replacing `myapp` with whereever your `UserProfile` app is and `1` with the correct ID. You will most likely get the same error so you will have to go onto the command line if so

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it from the shell!

You need some way to find that UserProfile, do you have an ID of the user or maybe of the UserProfile itself?

```
python manage.py shell
>>> from your_app_thing.models import UserProfile
>>> user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(id=<user profile id>)
>>> user_profile.remove()
```

Alternatively, you could add UserProfile to the admin panel?

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import UserProfile

admin.site.register(UserProfile)
```

Comment: unfortunately I don't have the ID of the user, the UserProfile is added to the admin site, and that's where I'm having the problem, I cannot enter there as I get the error (It's like it cannot load the page)